# What's the difference between this two codes? (Very JS beginner question)

Tags: javascript

This one prints:
Round 1: 24
Round 2: 32
Round 3: 17

```
var scores = [24, 32, 17]
var arrayLength = scores.length
var roundNumber = 0
var msg = ''
var i  

for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  roundNumber = (i + 1)

  msg += 'Round ' + roundNumber + ': '
  msg += scores[i] + '<br>'
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = msg

}
```

And this one prints:

Round 3: 22

```
var scores = [24, 23, 22]

for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
   msg = "Round " + (i + 1) + ":" + scores[i] + "<br>"
   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg
}
```

My question is: why doesn't the second one print all the three results like the first one?

Thank you.

Comment: Because you overwrite `msg` (and `.innerHTML`) with a new value on each iteration, instead of appending to it (with `+=`) after having it initialised to `''` before the loop.

Comment: In the first snippet, it would be a better to understand what happens if you put the `document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = msg` *after* the loop

Comment: First snippet aggregates output message, while in the second snippet only value of latest iteration is assigned to `msg` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are not concatenate string, msg change with each iteration.
Try this

```
var scores = [24, 23, 22]
var msg = ''
for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
   msg += "Round " + (i + 1) + ":" + scores[i] + "<br>"
   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg
}
```